# You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run nvidia-xconfig as root), and restart the X server

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, resolution

Im using Kubuntu 13.04 64-bit on my Dell Inspiron 17R laptop.

```
$ lspci|grep VGA:
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M / GTX 660M LE] (rev a1)
```

I tried to install NVIDIA drivers, firstly, from System/Additional Drivers but with no effect, then I did:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* 
sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia-* 
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get clean 
turned off all Additional Drivers from System/Additional drivers

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install bumblebee virtualgl linux-headers-generic bumblebee-nvidia

restarted my laptop

sudo apt-get install kde-window-manager 
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

and then tried:

```
# nvidia-xconfig nvidia-xconfig: no command found
```

So I did:

```
# apt-get install nvidia-common
```

but again .... :

```
# nvidia-xconfig
nvidia-xconfig: no command found
```

after all this, when I tried:

```
nvidia-settings
```

it showed me AGAIN: `You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run nvidia-xconfig as root), and restart the X server`

Help!

Comment: you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your accounts are merged.  Once done you will then be able to edit your question with further details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you didn't actually install the driver. Have you tried:

```
apt-get install nvidia-current
```

before running `nvidia-xconfig`?

Comment: Ok, tried it, now I can run `nvidia-xconfig` but even if it tells that it created a `xorg.conf` file, when I run `nvidia-settings` I see my message again: `You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver. Please edit your X configuration file (just run nvidia-xconfig as root), and restart the X server` and cannot plug in my monitor :(